# How to Load styles based on User login and Log Out

Tags: css, angular

I have a scenario where i have to load one style file before login and load another set of styles after login is it possible to implement  the same in angular?, Beacause all the styles and scripts required for the application are loaded through angular.json file . please let me know if there are any means to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

How about you add a css class on body or top level div on login. Then override any required css using that class.

Comment: Actually i have a scenario where i have before login screens and after login screens, i need to create such that i load the set of styles required beore login and another set of style files after login. but i have a file(angular.json) where i have added all the styles required for before login and after login but the thing my design is crashing due to CSS conflict. how do i overcome this problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can dynamically load styleUrls. But you can achieve this by declaring two classes in your SCSS file "login" and "logout". Then in your template file, use ngClass to switch between these classes. Example:
**.scss File**

```
.login {
...
}

.logout {
...
}
```

**.html file**

```
<div [ngClass]="{'login': isLoggedIn, 'logout': isLoggedOut}">
</div>
```

Where **isLoggedIn** and **isLoggedOut** are two flags you define in your ts. Manipulate these two flags according to your logic. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

it's only has a app.componet like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" [href]='cssUrl'>
<h1>Hello Angular</h1>
<button (click)="changeCss()">toogle css</button>
```

You app must be inject DomSanitizer and according with the value of one variable change the cssUrl variable

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  cssUrl: any;
  toogle:boolean=false;

  constructor(public sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.cssUrl = this.toogle?
      this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('./assets/style1.css') : 
      this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('./assets/style2.css');
  }
  changeCss()
  {
  this.toogle=!this.toogle
    this.cssUrl = this.toogle?this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('./assets/style1.css') : 
    this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('./assets/style2.css');
  }
}
```

See in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ox6cip?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

NOTE: To avoid the "flick" you can import the .css in your styles.css

```
@import './assets/style1.css';
@import './assets/style1.css';
```

Comment: Actually i have a scenario where i have before login screens and after login screens, i need to create such that i load the set of styles required beore login and another set of style files after login. but i have a file(angular.json) where i have added all the styles required for before login and after login but the thing my design is crashing due to CSS conflict. how do i overcome this problem

Comment: In angular.json you add the styles commons to all the application. You has in style1.css and style2.css only the .css that you want **override** -and, of course these are not declared in angular.json-